# How do I configure my nhibernate project to use memcached in the hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: nhibernate, memcached

I am trying to configure the hibernate.cfg.xml file to use memcache. I see the properties 
"cache.provider_class" and "cache.use_second_level_cache" however I do not see how I can add the server host/port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd set those properties in the `<memcache>` settings.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354419/nhibernate-caches-memcache-web-config-for-cache-expiration-time) for an example.

Comment: so inside the hibernate.cfg.xml but outside of the <hibernate-configuration> element?

Comment: No, in the web.config / app.config